# vertical navbar center align to viewport text not aligned

Tags: css, elementor

[image]I've vertically center aligned a menu in the viewport. The last menu item is not aligned with the rest of the navigation (see attachment). This is the custom css I applied:

```
.sidenav {

float: right;
width: 20px;
right: 20px;

}

.elementor-nav-menu--layout-vertical>ul {

transform: rotate(90deg);
display: flex;
height: 100vh;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;

}

.elementor-nav-menu--layout-vertical>ul>li {

margin-left: 20px;

}
```

Anyone have an idea why this last menu item is not aligned?

Comment: we need more code but is it aligned without rotation ?

Comment: please try creating a SO snippet where we can reproduce the actual issue. Or at least show your html.

Comment: Most likely, the last item in your menu has different `margin` `padding` than the previous ones.